# Disable sound in react-native-nfc-manager v2

Tags: react-native, nfc

Version 2 of react-native-nfc-manager is supposed to support disabling the scan sound (https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager/issues/60#issuecomment-464352677), however it doesn't seem to work.

This is the call:

```
NfcManager.registerTagEvent({

   alertMessage: 'my message',
    readerModeFlags: NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS

});
```

but it doesn't work...
Am I doing anything wrong?
I am using react-native 0.62.2, react-native-nfc-manager 2.1.7

Here is all the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View, Text, TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import NfcManager, {NfcEvents, NfcAdapter} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('NfcManager.start()')
    NfcManager.start();
    console.log('NfcManager.setEventListener()')
    NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, tag => {
      console.log('NfcEvents.DiscoverTag')
      console.warn('tag', tag);
      NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS('I got your tag!');
      //NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent().catch(() => 0);
    });
    this._listen();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, null);
    NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent().catch(() => 0);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 20}}>
        <Text>NFC Demo</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{padding: 10, width: 200, margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black'}}
          onPress={this._listen}
        >
          <Text>Listen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{padding: 10, width: 200, margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black'}}
          onPress={this._cancel}
        >
          <Text>Cancel listening</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  _cancel = () => {
    NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent().catch(() => 0);
  }

  _listen = async () => {
    try {
      //await NfcManager.registerTagEvent({alertMessage: 'my message', readerModeFlags: NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS});
      await NfcManager.registerTagEvent({
         alertMessage: 'my message',
         // when I added isReaderModeEnabled, tag scanning stopped working
         //isReaderModeEnabled: true,
         readerModeFlags: NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('ex', ex);
      NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent().catch(() => 0);
    }
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Impossible for ios, and supposed to work for android (it does work natively)
That undocumented Flag is very specific to the undocumented in this library Advanced Android Native direct `enableReaderMode` API usage.

The iOS NFC API's and the basic older Android API's have no control over the sounds made by the platform on Tag detection.

**Additional Android Specific**
And looking at the code for Android https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager/blob/master/android/src/main/java/community/revteltech/nfc/NfcManager.java

The following seems to be reported to partially work (I note that it sets other advanced options that mean it probably would only detect a tag once every 10 seconds)

```
NfcManager.registerTagEvent({

   alertMessage: 'my message',
   isReaderModeEnabled: true,
   readerModeFlags: NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS

});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. When I added isReaderModeEnabled, tag scanning stopped working...
I added all the code to my question.

Comment: I notice with the more code that you use `NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS` which is a platform specific method for IOS where as `FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS` is very specific to Android API >= 19.  Can you confirm which platform you are targeting as some of the NFC stuff is very platform specific.

Comment: I rechecked how this library works and with readerMode you need to also specify the card types in the `readerModeFlags` (exactly like you to in Native Java) so I've updated the answer to include most tag types, not having these extra flags would be consistent to tags being scanned and ignored BUT you would have had not sounds when they where scanned.

Comment: Should have check Platform for NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS... I am targeting both platforms. I thought that FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS is good for both platforms...

Comment: No `FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS` is very specific to Android API >= 19, You need to `NfcManager.registerTagEvent` in different ways to use `FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS`  IOS does not have this option.

Comment: Tested the updated flags on android, didn't help. I could scan a tag with these flags, but only once, while without the flags I could scan multiple times. So no way to disable sounds in iOS?

Comment: iOS has very limited NFC support compared to Android and in the Native iOS API https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc there is not ability to control sounds of NFC detection, in Android's more Advanced API there is this flag.  This library has very poor documentation for anything but the simple common NDEF tags, beyond this commonality between iOS and Android you basically using the different Native API's that are very platform specific

Comment: Thanks. I suggest that you hosts the answer saying that it is impossible for ios, and supposed to work for android but doesn't, so that I can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Updated the answer, I left in the Android specific stuff as I also note that in ReaderMode it also sets a flag that will probably cause it to only to detect a tag once every 10 seconds. (which is too long I use this same flag with a value of 0.25s )

Comment: Btw, in another issue related to nfc on iOS. Any idea if it is possible to prevent the iOS popup that is shown every time you enable nfc detection? If it is, can you please write me an email to yossi.glass@gmail.com? I would like to ask you something that doesn't belong here.